# How to join several xml files and convert to html

Tags: html, xml, jenkins, cppcheck

I have probably 20 different .xml files and I want to join them into a single file that contains the contents of these 20 files.

Afterwards I want to convert this new file to .html and update it to Jenkins.

Right now I'm also converting these 20 .xml files to .html as well because I don't know if it's easier to join those into one .html file.

Comment: By saying join, you mean doing a concatenation ? And by saying "convert to .html", you have an example of kind of xslt you want to apply ? Can you also give some examples of inputs (xml) and output you want (html) ?

Comment: This seems very similar to your [next question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643816/cppcheck-html-report)

Comment: `cppcheck-htmlreport` does not support input of multiple results - see https://trac.cppcheck.net/ticket/8955. I did not try the concatenation approach yet.