# CPPcheck html report

Tags: xml, linux, static-code-analysis, cppcheck

I have a question is there any way to generate one html file from few xml using cppcheck-htmlreport?

Normally I doing that:

`/cppcheck-htmlreport --file /vobs/stn/dev/linux/cppcheck/xmlreport_v1.xml --title "xml1 test" --report-dir .`

Now I want to do something like this

`/cppcheck-htmlreport --file /vobs/stn/dev/linux/cppcheck/*.xml --title "xml1 test" --report-dir .`

But when I did that commend cppcheck convert only one xml file...

Can anybody help me?

I'm sorry for my weak english.

Comment: `cppcheck-htmlreport` does not support input of multiple results - see https://trac.cppcheck.net/ticket/8955. I did not try the concatenation approach yet.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
cat *.xml >> newXmlFile.xml
```

before calling cppcheck-htmlreport? 
The cat-command concatenates the xml content of all xml files in the current folder and stores the result into newXmlFile.xml.